# Need help about do dynamic rowspans based on nested arrays length

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, vuejs2

I have an array of some data and arrays. Within the nested array there are some other arrays. I need to design an array based on the array length. The rowspans should be done based on the array length. How could  I do that? Someone help please

my array is something like this..

```
data: Array(2)
  0:
      details: Array(2)
        0:
        amount: (...)
        balance_quantity: (...)
        count_name: (...)
        lot_no: (...)
        quantity: (...)
        receive_date: (...)
        received_quantity: (...)
        unit_price: (...)
        yarn_count_composition: (...)

        1: 
        amount: (...)
        balance_quantity: (...)
        count_name: (...)
        lot_no: (...)
        quantity: (...)
        receive_date: (...)
        received_quantity: (...)
        unit_price: (...)
        yarn_count_composition: (...)

      lc_date: "2019-03-21"
      lc_no: "786"
      pi_no: "pi-677"
      supplier_id: 6
      Supplier_name: "Reedisha Blended Yarn Ltd"

  1:
     details: Array(4)
     lc_date: "2019-03-23"
     lc_no: "lc-70"
     pi_no: "pi-900"
     supplier_id: 3
     supplier_name: "Square Textiles Ltd"

​
```

```
 <tbody>
            <tr v-for="lcDetails in fields.data">
                <td style="text-align: center;"> </td>
                <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center;">{{lcDetails.supplier_name}}</td>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;"></td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">{{lcDetails.pi_no}}</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">{{lcDetails.lc_date}}</td>
                <template >
                    <td colspan="1">
                        <div v-for="details in lcDetails.details">
                            <p style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">{{details.count_name}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </template>

                <td colspan="3">

                    <div v-for="details in lcDetails.details">
                        <p style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">{{details.yarn_count_composition}}</p>
                    </div>
                </td>
</tr>
</tbody>


​
```

Comment: Can you share the data structure of array with an example?

Comment: @sajal can ypu please look at this?

Comment: You just need to set the value of `<td colspan="1">` based on the count of elements in `lcDetails.details`, right?

Comment: yap, but how can I count different element in the nested array?

Comment: try this : `<td colspan="lcDetails.details.length">`, you might have to interpolate the vaue.